# Как поменять аватар?

Tags: поддержка, faq, user-interface

Как поменять аватар?
После переезда не вижу этой опции.
(+)
Кстати, в старом формате стандартный смотрелся органично, а тут (в силу более частого употребления, что ли) начал резать глаз.
(++)
Господи, ну почему система так не любит короткие вопросы? ну сколько мне еще ерунды сюда вбивать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В профиле Меты поменять его нельзя (если в этом проблема).

Нужно перейти на основной сайт, нажать на свой значок в шапке сайта (там где репутация и "знаки"), откроется страница профиля. Там три ссылки - Профиль, активность, править. Жмем на "править" и в открывшейся странице есть ссылка "изменить изображение" (прямо на картинке-аватаре).

Comment: Спасибо, нашел.   (+) Нет, я не имел в виду что-то менять на Мете. Я почему-то не видел этой кнопки именно на "основном" сайте, т.е. на Русском языке. После его переезда все стало  как в чужом доме: ничего найти не могу. Спасибо хоть, что репутацию сохранили.